# Deserialization output error in /adAnalytics, Array parameter 'companies' value is invalid?

Tags: linkedin-api

I get the following error:
`'Array parameter 'companies' value 'List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A12345)' is invalid. Reason: Deserializing output 'List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A12345)' failed' status: 400`

I'm using the 'Linkedin-Version': '202304'.
I'm trying to make a get request to the `/adAnalytics` route.
I'm structuring the option params in the following way:

```
const companyURN = encodeURIComponent(company.organization);
{
          q: 'analytics',
          timeGranularity: 'DAILY',
          pivot: pivot,
          'companies': `List(${companyURN})`,
          'dateRange.start.year': dateFns.format(startDate, 'yyyy'),
          'dateRange.start.month': dateFns.format(startDate, 'MM'),
          'dateRange.start.day': dateFns.format(startDate, 'dd'),
          'dateRange.end.year': dateFns.format(endDate, 'yyyy'),
          'dateRange.end.month': dateFns.format(endDate, 'MM'),
          'dateRange.end.day': dateFns.format(endDate, 'dd'),
          fields: measurementChunk.join(',') + ',pivotValue,dateRange',
}
```

The error comes from the parameter 'companies' :

On the documentation, here is the request example:
GET [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&pivot={pivot}&timeGranularity={time}&dateRange={dateRange}&{facet}=List({URN_1},{URN_2})](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&pivot=%7Bpivot%7D&timeGranularity=%7Btime%7D&dateRange=%7BdateRange%7D&%7Bfacet%7D=List(%7BURN_1%7D,%7BURN_2%7D))

For 'companies', the description mentions as follows:  `Match result by company facets. Defaults to empty.` And the type of `Array of Organization URN`. If we look at the organization urn it will be structured as follows: `urn:li:organization:12345`.

I've tried different variations, including:

```
          // 'companies[0]': company.organization,
          // 'companies[0]': companyURN,
          // 'companies': `List(${companyURN})`,
          // 'companies[0]': `${companyURN}`,
```

But all gave the same deserialization error.

Here are some links used:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2023-04&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-04&tabs=http